# Does the e.matches() method traverse the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Does the e.matches() method have to traverse the DOM to evaluate the selector?

I ask because of a situation such as:

```
if ( e.matches('.class_1, .class_1 *') {
  /* Do something. */
} else if ( e.matches('.class_2, .class_2 *') {
  /* Do something. */
} else if ( e.matches('.class_3, .class_3 *') {
  /* Do something. */
} else {
  /* Do something. */
}
```

If the DOM is traversed from the element `e` up the ancestor tree to determine if e.matches() is true/false; then it would repeat the process for each `else if` when the previous condition is false. So, I wondered if this was not inefficient and I should just loop up the ancestor tree once using `e.classList.contains()` to find which of the set (class_1, class_2, class_3) is encountered first or reach an ancestor element that indicates that should stop searching. But `contains()` doesn't appear to be a quick test either.

```
let c = e.classList;
while ( e ) {
  if ( c.contains('class_1') ) {
    /* Do something. */
    break;
  } else if ( c.contains('class_2') ) {
    /* Do something. */
    break;
  } else if ( c.contains('class_3') ) {
    /* Do something. */
    break;
  }
  e = e.parentNode;
}
```

In this DOM sturcture class_1 is always deeper down than class_2 which is always deeper down than class_3. So, I'd like to determine to which level `e` belongs first. Which element is the class_1, 2, 3 does not need to be determined, but only to which of them (if any) `e` is closest to on the way up the tree.

Thank you.

ADDED 24 DEC 2023

It's been a few months since thinking about this and tried this small example. The results are a bit unexpected, in that `e.closest()` and `e.matches()` are just about the same and very fast when there is a matching element; but, when there is not a match, then `e.closest()` is much slower and `e.matches()` is the same. Ran this in Firefox. Tried in Brave and 5000 iterations causes it to crash in SO; but it ran for fewer iterations and the resuls are similar.

By unexpected, I mean, if `e.closest()` has to step upward through the DOM until it fines a match, then why does it not take the same time to find `evt_1` (at the very outside) as it does to find that there is not an `evt_2`? Both would have to step through all 5000 levels.

It appears that the documentation (https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-element-closest%E2%91%A0), although I don't understand what it means exactly, indicates there is a difference in process between the two methods. When there is a match, there is no time difference between `evt_3` at 2500 level and `evt_1` at 5000, if count from the inside outward.

```js
var
  D = document.createElement("DIV"),
  d = D;
D.className = "evt_1";
for ( let i = 0; i < 5000; i++ ) {
  d = d.appendChild(document.createElement("DIV"));
  if ( i === 2500 ) d.className = "evt_3";
}  

document.body.append(D);
let t = Date.now();
console.log( d.matches(".evt_1, .evt_1 *") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );
t = Date.now();
console.log( d.closest(".evt_1, .evt_1 *") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );
t = Date.now();
console.log( d.closest(".evt_1") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );

t = Date.now();
console.log( d.matches(".evt_2, .evt_2 *") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );
t = Date.now();
console.log( d.closest(".evt_2, .evt_2 *") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );
t = Date.now();
console.log( d.closest(".evt_2") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );

t = Date.now();
console.log( d.matches(".evt_3, .evt_3 *") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );
t = Date.now();
console.log( d.closest(".evt_3, .evt_3 *") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );
t = Date.now();
console.log( d.closest(".evt_3") + " " + (Date.now() - t) );

/*
true 0
[object HTMLDivElement] 0
false 0
null 112
true 0
[object HTMLDivElement] 0
*/
```

Comment: _"inefficient ... doesn't appear to be a quick test"_... what does your profiling tell you? How are you measuring performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to traverse the ancestor list so there might be some waste, but traversing it yourself once might not be faster than the browser traversing it 3 times.

If the site has a noticable performance issue (e.g. if this operation is performed a lot of times), you can measure both methods on different browsers and see what's faster. But in most cases there wouls be practically no difference anyway and then it's probably better to go with what makes the code clearer.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Even if `e.matches()` is run three times starting at `e` each time, what the browser does in C or whatever low-level language it is using, it'll most likely be quicker than writing something in JS that tries to iterate once but check for three class items at each parent node. Plus, the browser must be efficient at checking CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it seems that you want the element method [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) using a [selector list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list) of your class names:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".clickable").forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.currentTarget.closest(".class_1, .class_2, .class_3"));
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="class_3">
    <div class="class_2">
      <div class="class_1">
        <div class="clickable">Click 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="class_3">
    <div class="class_2">
      <div class="clickable">Click 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="class_3">
    <div class="clickable">Click 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer rather than mine... I missed that this exists as a built-in method

Comment: @Noam I was aware of this method but do not see it as a definite improvement. It appears that it does about what the second block of code in my question does. We know `.closest()` traverses the DOM because it returns the match and the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) tell us so. We do not know that `e.matches()` traverses the DOM.  It may be making use of something created when processing the style sheet the first time. I don't want the element that is closest; I just want to know in which level the element of interest is locacted.

Comment: The `e.matches()` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) read "The matches() method of the Element interface tests whether the element would be selected by the specified CSS selector." The `e.closest()` doc reads "The closest() method of the Element interface traverses the element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the specified CSS selector." I read them before posting the question but could not determine what `e.matches()` really does.

Comment: And, although nice to know (and thank you @jsejcksn for the response) this answer returns the first node in the tree having one of the three classes of interest. It still needs to test which of the three classes that node contains. It appears that the only way to know which approach is quicker is to performance test it or know what `e.matches()` really does.

Comment: @Gary In that case, yes, you’d still need to discriminate which class was found on the closest ancestor, but you can be certain that the native code in the runtime will be more performant than a JavaScript search implementation.

Comment: Sure, I agree that the `closest()` method would be faster than my sample code testing each node using `contains()`. And I'm glad you showed it because I didn't realize that more than one selector string could be included.

Comment: Since I placed the links to those other docs here, one more that I could not decipher is (https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-element-closest%E2%91%A0). It describes the process for `closesst()` and `matches()`. It would appear that `matches()` does not traverse the DOM but I really don't know what is involved in the Step 1. parse a selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the "heavy" work outside any of the loops by analysing the classes that have been assigned to the clicked (or otherwise selected) element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(d=>d.onclick=e=>{
  const classes=Object.fromEntries([...e.target.classList].map(cl=>([cl,1])));
  // classes is an object that has class-named properties. These can be easily checked for existence:
  if (classes.class_1) console.log("A class 1 element was clicked");
  else if (classes.class_2) console.log("A class 2 element was clciked");
  else if (classes.class_3) console.log("A class 3 element was clciked");
})
```

```css
.class_1,.class_2,.class_3 {cursor:pointer; background-color:#ddd; margin:6px}
```

```html
<p>Please click on any of the divs below:</p>
<div class="class_1">class 1 item</div>
<div class="class_2">class 2 item</div>
<div class="class_3">class 3 item</div>
<div class="class_1 class_2">class 1 and 2 item</div>
<div class="class_2 class_3">class 2 and 3 item</div>
<div class="class_3 class_1">class 3 and 1 item</div>
```

Seeing that your sequence of `if` statements always filters out the alphabetically lowest "class_..." entry you can simplify the script further to:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div[class*=class_]").forEach(d=>d.onclick=e=>{
  const minClass=[...e.target.classList].filter(c=>c.slice(0,6)=="class_").reduce((a,c)=>c<a?c:a)
  if      (minClass=="class_1") console.log("A class 1 element was clicked");
  else if (minClass=="class_2") console.log("A class 2 element was clciked");
  else if (minClass=="class_3") console.log("A class 3 element was clciked");
})
```

```css
.class_1,.class_2,.class_3 {cursor:pointer; background-color:#ddd; margin:6px}
```

```html
<p>Please click on any of the divs below:</p>
<div class="class_1">class 1 item</div>
<div class="class_2">class 2 item</div>
<div class="class_3">class 3 item</div>
<div class="extraClass">this chould not be clickable</div>
<div class="class_1 abc class_2">class 1 and 2 item</div>
<div class="class_2 class_3">class 2 and 3 item</div>
<div class="class_3 class_1">class 3 and 1 item</div>
```